# Handling Multiple functionalities in Firebase using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hellow all,

I'm Newbie to Nodejs and Firebase, I need two functionalities to takes place in a single function and also I have written a piece of code it's works fine.

But My question is, the code I have written is the correct way to  achieve the multiple functionality or do we have any other alternate method(correct way) to achieve the same functionality.

**Doubt :
Retrieving relevant details of project ----> Inside Callback function ----> saving data to another table ----> Inside Callback function ----> Deleting data from table  -----> Inside Callback function ----> response**

Do we need to write the functionality inside the nested callback function to achieve the output or is there is any other way to achieve it .

```
// Nodejs Post Function 
app.post('/delete_user_request_project/', function (req, res) 
{ 
    if (!is_admin_login(req.cookies.login_type)) 
    {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }

    var project_id = req.body.project_id; // Getting the project Id
    let del_ref = admin.database().ref("user_request_project/" + project_id);   // Targeting the  details of the project to fetch that particular data 
    del_ref.once("value", function (snapshot) 
    {
        var request_project_obj = snapshot.val(); // fetching the details of project 
        if (request_project_obj != null) 
        {   
            let update_ref = admin.database().ref("deleted_user_request_project/" + project_id);
            update_ref.set(
                request_project_obj         // Updating project details to another table 
            ).then(function () 
            {  
                del_ref.remove().then(function () // Deleting the details from project Table 
                {
                    return res.status(200).send('success');
                });
            });            
        }
        else 
        {
            var error = "プロジェクトが存在しない";
            req.flash("error", error_message);
            return res.send({
                status: 'error',
                error: error
            });
        }
    });
})
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the Promise version of the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) method instead of the Callback version, as follows. It will allow you to correctly [chain the different promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) returned by the asynchronous Firebase method.

```
app.post('/delete_user_request_project/', function (req, res) {
    if (!is_admin_login(req.cookies.login_type)) {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }

    var project_id = req.body.project_id; // Getting the project Id
    let del_ref = admin.database().ref("user_request_project/" + project_id);   // Targeting the  details of the project to fetch that particular data 
    del_ref.once("value")
        .then(function (snapshot) {
            var request_project_obj = snapshot.val(); // fetching the details of project 

            if (request_project_obj != null) {
                let update_ref = admin.database().ref("deleted_user_request_project/" + project_id);
                return update_ref.set(request_project_obj);         // Updating project details to another table 
            }
            else {
                throw new Error('request_project_obj null');
            }
        })
        .then(function () {
            return del_ref.remove();
        })
        .then(function () // Deleting the details from project Table 
        {
            return res.status(200).send('success');
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            if (error.message === 'request_project_obj null') {
                var error = "プロジェクトが存在しない";
                req.flash("error", error_message);
                return res.send({
                    status: 'error',
                    error: error
                });
            } else {
                //...
            }

        })

})
```